# What would be the future of libraries in the next 100 years of the digital age?

Tags: science-based, evolution, near-future

A library is a beautiful storehouse of knowledge. With the advent of digital technology, many books and publications are taking the digital route through e-books. Resources are becoming easily accessible via internet and they are on the rise everyday.

When I joined college, five years back, students had no other option but to take photocopies of books required for the syllabus. In just the next 3 years, smartphones were available to take photographs of the required pages from a book and then it was shared with other students.

By the time I'm 70 years old, I believe that digitized copies of most books would be available online, video tutorials and webinars may become the norm and also more and more content will be available in regional and local languages across the globe, making it even easier for all the people.

Based on this I would like to ask these questions,

1. Will people use libraries in the future?
2. How will old books be preserved in the future?
3. How will the libraries evolve for the future?

Comment: Hi Vijay, welcome to Worldbuilding. Could you specify what you mean by "future"? Tomorrow isn't the same as in 1,000,000 years from now. Yet both are in the future..?

Comment: Hi bilbo, By mentioning 'future', I meant the next 100 years

Comment: You should consider editing your question to clarify that :-)

Comment: Please check my edit, Bilbo

Comment: Welcome to the site Vijay.  This is an interesting question but without knowing what your future looks like the answer could be one of a limitless number of possibilities.  If you can provide a scenario or otherwise narrow this down we can provide you an answer.

Comment: I think this is opinion based, because different people will have different views of what will happen to books. But if everything goes digital, send me your books.

Comment: To all the poeple who have put the question on hold, please check my edit. I have added more info of how 'my future would look like'.

Comment: @VijayMaximOff, when you edit your question after it was placed on-hold, it appears automatically in a reopen review queue. So at least 5 persons will review whether the newer version fits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Vijay welcome to the site,

I think that in 100 years there will still be lots of books which won't be digitized and even if they would be, it is a really different feeling having a 400 years old book in your hands than reading just its content. 
So for research the old (original) books will still be needed.

Also, libraries (especially those at universities) are nice places to learn or research because you have all the information from the library **and** from the internet. An additional bonus is that those places are always silent and you don't get distracted so often.

And to answer your last question I could imagine libraries also sell/lend ebooks in the future. Like Netflix for books :D

Hope I could help you.

As always: I am really trying to improve my english, so if you find a mistake feel free to correct it.